# Why is panic recover buf size 64 << 10?

Tags: go, stack

I see so many code snippets which panic recover in golang. Just looks like:

```
func PanicRecover(c context.Context) {
    if e := recover(); e != nil {
        const size = 64 << 10
        buf := make([]byte, size)
        buf = buf[:runtime.Stack(buf, false)]
        logs.CtxError(c, "Error: %s", string(buf))
    }
}
```

I want to know why buffer size is always 64 << 10.

Comment: It was probably just copied from the stdlib or a popular tutorial. 64k just happens to be a useful size.

Comment: This is just copy paste. (64 << 10) - 123 is fine too.